# Recursively watch for new elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am looking for a way to recursively watch for new elements in an iframe in plain Javascript (no jQuery). The part that is tricky is that each iframe may have several other iframes inside it.

Is there a way to watch for new elements, even ones nested in an iframe?

Sample Structure:

```
div
  iframe
     head
     body
       div
         iframe
            head
            body
              div
                div
                  iframe
```

Current codebase:

```
function add_listener(element) {
  element.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName == "iframe") {
      add_listener(event.target.contentDocument)
    }
  })
}

add_listener(document)
```

Comment: Sounds like a big task. What have you got so far?

Comment: Write now I have an event listener for new dom elements but it is only working at one layer. One of the major problems is that when I add an event listener to the iframe, it could get removed if 3rd-party code does a document.write()

Comment: Yeah, we need to see your literal code to see what kind of thing you're actually doing, so then we can help figure out how to make it recursive and so on.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I have added the current code. Thank you for the help! One other problem with this code is it does not handle `document.write` which will clear all event listeners. Adding the event listener after the `write` will not catch all elements that have been inserted with the write method.

Comment: Okay, here's a few points you should think about:

Comment: 1. events bubble, so you can just stick a single listener on the document and all events will go through it. There shouldn't be any need to re-add the listeners to any other elements.

Comment: 2. `document.write` will kill the entire page if it's already loaded, so do you still care what's on the page at that point? Or if the page hasn't loaded, it'll just insert some HTML from where script is being run from, so nothing bad will happen to your listeners. Also, have you actually tested to see if the listener is removed after a `document.write`? I'm not sure why that would happen.

Comment: 3. `DOMNodeInserted` and other mutation events are now deprecated. I gather [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the new way of doing such things?

Comment: I don't know if any of those help. I don't really understand why you'd want to do this, so I'm finding it difficult to know what will help and what won't.

Comment: Thanks @Whothehellisthat. I am doing it because I am looking for certain elements in the iframes that have a specific url. I need to be able to track the number of times those urls have appeared.

Comment: Okay. So just the links?

Are any of those other points useful, maybe?

Comment: The MutationObserver helped alot. Thanks